# Deploying inter dependent stacks at once with CDKTF

Tags: terraform, cdktf

I'm using CDKTF version 0.9.4 to deploy two stacks associated with an app. The [docs](https://www.terraform.io/cdktf/cli-reference/commands#deploy) says I have to simply list'em all or use '*'.

Running `cdktf deploy '*'` I get: `Can't find the given stack *`. I then listed all of'em and received `Unable to find remote state`, what me think whether cross-dependency is available only for cloud usage.

On the other hand, [this](https://www.terraform.io/cdktf/concepts/stacks) tells me that multiple deployment stack isn't available, even though [this dude](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdicN25Fkec&ab_channel=HashiCorp) does it.

I'm using Python, so maybe that's the problem ?

Any help is appreciated.

The cross-stack dependency was declared in two ways (errors were the same):

1. Exposing the objects as property of the stack

```
first_stack = Lambda(app, "my-lambda")
second_stack = ApiGateway(app, "api_gateway", first_stack.lambda_function)
```

2. Using `add_dependency()` method. Not sure I'm doing this right, the former seems more appropriate

```
first_stack = Lambda(app, "my-lambda")
second_stack = ApiGateway(app, "api_gateway", first_stack.lambda_function)
second_stack.add_dependency(first_stack)
```

Comment: The feature to use a wildcard was introduced in version 0.10, and you're using 0.9.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As kornshell93 already said, you need to update your cdktf version to 0.10 or higher since the feature was just recently introduced. In 0.9 you should be able to run `cdktf deploy first-stack && cdktf deploy second-stack` though, since cross stack references were in place already.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. Kornshell93 suggestion worked just fine. I hadn't noticed that it was >=0.1.